# Wrong number or types of arguments in call

Tags: python, sql

El objetivo del ejercicio que estoy resolviendo se centra en crear un procedimiento dentro de un paquete en sql developer el cual insertará en una tabla llamada B de una sola columna un conjunto de números(en concreto 100), llamando a dicho procedimiento des de Python.

Creo que la estructura que se ha seguido es la correcta. El único problema viene cuando intentamos hacer la llamada desde Python o des de SQL y nos aparece el error del título. No sabemos a que es debido, puesto que le pasamos lo que pide. Adjunto código del paquete y del script de python:

Código Paquete SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Pack AS 
TYPE num_array IS VARRAY(100) OF NUMBER;
PROCEDURE procediment_1 ( arr IN num_array );
END Pack;
```

Código Cuerpo Paquete:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY PACK AS  
PROCEDURE procediment_1 (arr in num_array) AS
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..arr.COUNT LOOP
  INSERT INTO B VALUES (arr(i));
END LOOP;
END;
END Pack;
```

Código Python:

```
import cx_Oracle

cur = conn.cursor()
lista = []
x=0
while x < 100:
RandomNumero = random.randint(0, 1000)

if RandomNumero not in lista:
    lista.append(RandomNumero)
    x += 1


num_array = cur.arrayvar(cx_Oracle.NUMBER, lista)
cur.callproc("PACK.procediment_1", [num_array])
conn.commit()
```

El cursor funciona perfectamente. La conexión a la base de datos es correcta y está verificado. Solo nos ocurre ese error, tanto en sql como en python.

ERROR:
cur.callproc("PACK.procediment_1", args)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROCEDIMENT_1'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored